# Which two clauses should be compounded in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, compounds

> He asked a lot of questions  which were none of his business and
>   generally managed to annoy everybody.

[image]

Which one is right, and why ?

I'm an English learner and it's refer from a book. It's just confuse me.

Comment: What is the intended meaning of the sentence?

Comment: @SteveES I think that means he asked a lot of bad questions and made everyone feel bad.

Comment: Are you trying to work out the meaning of the sentence? Has the sentence been given to you by someone else?

Comment: @SteveES I'm an English learner and it's refer from a book. It's just confuse me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both interpretations of the sentence are correct, but convey subtly different meanings. The meaning could have been clarified if they had added commas and chosen "which" or "that" appropriately.

1. The first interpretation would be more obviously the intended
   meaning if "that" had been used instead of "which", and repeated:

   > He asked a lot of questions **that** were none of his business and **that** generally managed to annoy everybody.

   This implies the meaning that the many questions he asked that were
   none of his business also annoyed everyone. In other words, everything
   after **that** is extra information about the **questions** he asked. It
   does not imply that he was generally annoying in other ways, but
   that his questions were generally annoying.
2. The second interpretation would be more obviously the intended
   meaning if commas and an extra "he" were added:

   > He asked a lot of questions, which were none of his business, and he generally managed to annoy everybody.

   Here, the questions he asked are not the reason why he annoyed
   everyone. The fact that he asked questions and the fact that he
   annoyed everyone are separate statements; "which were none of his
   business" is there to add extra information about the questions. (We
   can still imply, however, that him asking lots of questions that
   were none of his business was annoying.) In this interpretation we
   can swap the order of the sentence, so the following would mean the
   same thing:

   > He generally managed to annoy everybody and asked a lot of questions which were none of his business.

I think that (2) is probably the intended meaning given the phrase **generally managed**, which implies a wider scope for the annoyance than the questions, and the use of "which" instead of "that". However, as written, it is ambiguous as to whether "*generally managed to annoy everybody*" refers to "**him**" or "**questions**", so both interpretations are valid.

Comment: Would the second interpretation be more obviously the intended meaning if **only** commas **but not** an extra "he" were added? Is it ambiguous?

Comment: Yes, I think it would be more likely to indicate meaning 2, but it would still be ambiguous.

Answer (score 7):

Both alternants are plausible, though it’s not about 'compounding' two clauses, but about a coordination of two verb phrases.

> [1]  *He asked a lot of questions which [were none of his business] and
>   [generally managed to annoy everyone].*
>
> [2]  *He [asked a lot of questions which were none of his business], and
>   [generally managed to annoy everyone].*

In [1], the coordination is of the two bracketed verb phrases. In this reading, the criticisms were entirely of his questions, which were none of his business and annoyed everyone.

In [2], the coordination is of two different verb phrases, in brackets, and in this reading, the criticisms are of two separate things: his questions for being none of his business, and him for annoying everyone.

In writing, the two meanings should be distinguishable if a comma is inserted in [2] before "and", as shown. But in speech there would be no way of distinguishing the two meanings unless there was a pronounced pause before "and" – but even that would not be a foolproof guide and ambiguity may well arise.

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct sentences.

We can interpret "generally managed to annoy everybody" to describe him or to describe the questions.

> At the party I met a pretty girl who was Italian and was wearing a pretty dress.  The Italian said that she liked my pretty dress.